# Router View in a child of a component doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to use this structure in my router file:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  children: [
    { path: 'users', name: 'Users', component: Users },
    { path: 'permissions', name: 'Permissions', component: Permissions },
    { path: 'systems', name: 'Systems', component: Systems }
  ]
},
```

But it doesn't work. The url path change but the components are not rendered.

My Dashboard component template is like this:

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid" data-ma-theme="green">
  <main class="main">
    <header-layout></header-layout>
    <aside-layout></aside-layout>
    <content-layout></content-layout>
  </main>
</div>
</template>
```

And my router view are in the content component like this:

```
<template>
   <section class="content">
    <VuePerfectScrollbar class="scroll-area" v-once :settings="settings">
       <router-view/>
    </VuePerfectScrollbar>
  </section>
</template>
```

i don't know how to tell the Dashboard path that the childs are in the content component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `<router-view/>` inside component template not inside child tag. This `<VuePerfectScrollbar/>` is going to replace with your component template.Means all other things will be lost

Inside `VuePerfectScrollbar` template

```
<template>
<div>
   Other things
    ..............
    <router-view/>
    .......
    Other things
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It Work! it happens because the vueperfectscrollbar has a template inside to, isn't it? is the context of dashboard component lost ?