# Info not displaying in modal, however no errors and Vue component works in console

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Looking to display data in a modal.  My set up is as follows:

app.js

```
Vue.component('modal', require('./components/Modal.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data() {
        return {
            id: '',
            booking_start: '',
            booking_end: '',
            car: [],
            user: []
        };
    },
});
```

Modal.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <slot name="header"></slot>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <slot name="footer"></slot>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'modal',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Modal mounted.')
        },
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        props: ['id', 'booking_start', 'car', 'user'],
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Laravel blade:

```
<div id="vue">
        <modal v-bind="{{json_encode($reservation)}}">
            <template slot="header">
                <strong>Vehicle Checkout</strong>
            </template>
            <p>Ready to check out this vehicle?</p>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Name</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-name">@{{ car.name }}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Make / Model</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-make-model"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Registration</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-registration"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Odometer Start</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-odometer"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <template slot="footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
            </template>
        </modal>
    </div>
```

At this point, I am just attempting to get the data to show in the modal.

Looking at the Vue Dev tools:

[image: Vue Dev Tools]

There are no errors in the console, and I can output the data I am after in the console.

I'm probably missing something very basic as I am new to Vue, but I can't for the life of me work out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component tag replaced by template content, so put all content into `modal` component from component tag `<modal>.your content.</modal>`

```js
Vue.component('modal',{
  props:['car'],
  template: `<div><template slot="header">
                <strong>Vehicle Checkout</strong>
            </template>
            <p>Ready to check out this vehicle?</p>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Name</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-name">{{ car.name }}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Make / Model</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-make-model">{{ car.model }}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vehicle Registration</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-registration">{{ car.reg }}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Odometer Start</th>
                    <td><span id="reservation-car-odometer">{{ car.odo }}</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <template slot="footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
            </template>
            </div>`
})


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data() {
        return {
            id: '',
            booking_start: '',
            booking_end: '',
            car: {name:'test1',model:'gh201',reg:'201821542',odo:'2018-01-01'},
            user: []
        };
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <modal :car="car"></modal>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My other answers related this issue : [router view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605076/router-view-in-a-child-of-a-component-doesnt-work/47605111#47605111) and [transition-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892865/transition-group-inside-v-for-statement-in-vue-js-2/49894624#49894624)

Comment: Does this lose the ability to reuse the modal component elsewhere though, as it no longer uses slots?

Comment: And how would I access the other non-car props?

Comment: I didn't use slot but you can , I just wanted to let you know that component tag is replaced by templates content.

Comment: @kerrin : you can put all object into one say `udata` and then use like `udata.car` to get value of `car`

Comment: @kerrin : If you still have some doubt then share your live snippet as I did.